# Authorization_code grant flow on Owin.Security.OAuth: returns invalid_grant

Tags: asp.net, oauth-2.0, owin, owin.security

I am trying to setup my authentication using the `authorization_code` grant flow. I had it previously working with `grant_type=password`, so I kind of know how the stuff is supposed to work. But when using `grant_type=authorization_code`, I couldn't make it return anything other than `invalid_grant`

Here is my setup:

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/auth/token"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
    Provider = new SampleAuthProvider()
});

app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
    AuthenticationType = "Bearer"
});
```

SampleAuthProvider is the following class: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8a0079b705423b406c00

Basically, it's just logging every step and validating it. I tried the request:

```
POST http://localhost:12345/auth/token
grant_type=authorization_code&code=xxxxxx&client_id=xxxxx&redirect_uri=https://xxxx.com/
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

It's going through:

- `OnMatchEndpoint`
- `OnValidateClientAuthentication`

And that's all. I expected it to call `OnValidateTokenRequest` and `OnGrantAuthorizationCode`next, but it just didn't. I have no idea why.

The `xxxx`'s in the request aren't placeholders, I tried it like that. Maybe the middleware makes some checks on its own and rejects the request because of that? I tried variants of the `redirect_uri` with `http`, without any protocol, without trailing slash...

It also works properly with a custom `grant_type`. It  so if I too desperate, I guess I can use that to simulate `authorization_code`, but I'd rather not have to do that.

**TL;DR**

My `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` returns `{"error":"invalid_grant"}`after `OnValidateClientAuthentication` when using `grant_type=authorization_code`.

- Why is it stopping there?
- How can I make the whole damn thing work?

Thanks for your help!

---

**Edit**

As pointed out by RajeshKannan, I made a mistake in my configuration. I didn't provide an `AuthorizationCodeProvider` instance. However, that didn't completely solve the problem, since in my case, the code is not issued by the `AuthorizationCodeProvider`, and I can't just deserialize it. I anwered with the workaround I got working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what I got working. I'm not completely comfortable with that solution, but it works and should help others to fix their issues.

---

So, the issue is that I didn't set the `AuthorizationCodeProvider` property. When a request with `grant_type=authorization_code` is received, the code must be validated by that code provider. The framework assumes that the code was issued by that code provider, but that's not my case. I get it from another server and have to send the code back to it for validation.

In the standard case, where you are also the one issuing the code, the link provided by RajeshKannan describes everything you have to do.

Here is where you have to set the property:

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(Paths.TokenPath),
    Provider = new SampleAuthProvider(),
    AuthorizationCodeProvider = new MyAuthorizationCodeProvider ()
}
```

And the declaration of the `MyAuthorizationCodeProvider` class:

```
internal class MyAuthorizationCodeProvider : AuthenticationTokenProvider
{
    public override async Task ReceiveAsync(
        AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        object form;
        // Definitely doesn't feel right
        context.OwinContext.Environment.TryGetValue(
                "Microsoft.Owin.Form#collection", out form); 
        var redirectUris = (form as FormCollection).GetValues("redirect_uri");
        var clientIds = (form as FormCollection).GetValues("client_id");
        if (redirectUris != null && clientIds != null)
        {
            // Queries the external server to validate the token
            string username = await MySsoService.GetUserName(context.Token,
                                                             redirectUris[0]);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
            {
                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim>()
                {
                    // I need the username in  GrantAuthorizationCode
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, username) 
                }, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);

                var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties();

                // Required. The request is rejected if it's not provided
                authProps.Dictionary.Add("client_id", clientIds[0]); 

                // Required, must be in the future
                authProps.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1); 

                var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, authProps);
                context.SetTicket(ticket);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @scenario, did you manage to find a better way? I'm with the same issue

Comment: Sorry, I stopped working on that project so I have no further updates on that topic. That solution worked well though. The API is just designed with other use cases in mind. Maybe in future updates that will be doable without hardcoded keys, casts and co.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error. Things I was missing:

- Specify `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions.AuthorizationCodeProvider` according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server).
- Specify the same `client_id` as a GET-parameter when making a request to the token endpoint as you did when you received the `authorization_code`.
- Override `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.ValidateClientAuthentication` and in this method call `context.TryGetFormCredentials`. This sets the property `context.ClientId` to the value from the `client_id` GET-parameter. This property [must be set](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/b850cd8b4de61e65bbd7127ce02b5df7c4cb6db5/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs#L517), otherwise you'll get the `invalid_grant` error. Also, call `context.Validated()`.

After doing all of the above, I could finally exchange the `authorization_code` to an `access_token` at the token endpoint.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm doing all this, but while my implementations for `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.ValidateClientAuthentication` and `IAuthenticationTokenProvider.ReceiveAsync` get called (in that order), my implementation for `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantAuthorizationCode` never gets triggered and I end up getting 400: invalid_grant.

Comment: plus 1 though since the client_id suggestion was good and indeed required.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks scenario, My code was missing the following two required values. Posted here in case others find it useful:

```
            // Required. The request is rejected if it's not provided
            authProps.Dictionary.Add("client_id", clientIds[0]); 

            // Required, must be in the future
            authProps.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have configured your authorization server options.
I think you should provide your authorize end point details:

```
 AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString(Paths.AuthorizePath)
```

In the below link, the authorization code grant will be explained in detail and it lists the method which were involved in authorization code grant life cycle.

[Owin Oauth authorization server](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-oauth-20-authorization-server)

Comment: Thanks your answer put me on the right track. I edited the question to explain what I had to change. But it just feels weird. Am I missing an easier way to get the query parameters and pass them to Provider? Or maybe I'm not supposed to contact my SSO Server like that?

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @dgn more or less worked for me. This is just an extension to that. As it turns out, you can supply whatever string you want to the `ClaimsIdentity` constructor. The following works just as well, and doubles up as a detailed code comment:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
    @"Katana - What a shitty framework/implementation.
    Unintuitive models and pipeline, pretty much have to do everything, and the docs explain nothing. 
    Like what can go in here? WTF knows but turns out as long as _something_ is in here, 
    there is a client_id key in your AuthenticationProperties with the same value as 
    what's set inside your implementation for OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.ValidateClientAuthentication, and
    your AuthenticationProperties.ExpiresUtc is set to some time in the future, it works.
    Oh and you don't actually need to supply an implementation for OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantAuthorizationCode...
    but if you are using the resource owner grant type, you _do_ need to supply an implementation of 
    OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials. Hmm. Whatever.
    Katana and IdenetityServer - two frameworks that are absolute garbage. In the amount of time it took me to
    figure out all the observations in this paragraph, I could've written my own /token endpoint."
);
```

Comment: I've fallen for this trap multiple times  It has nothing to do with those frameworks, but you need to pass an authentication type to the constructor if you want an authenticated identity, this can be found in the remarks in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.isauthenticated?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the the following simplest example and would like to share it. Hope someone find it helpful.

--

It seems the middleware will check if the key `redirect_uri` exists in the dictionary of `AuthenticationProperties`, remove it and everything works fine(with validated context).

A simplified example of `AuthorizationCodeProvider` woubld be like so:

```
public class AuthorizationCodeProvider:AuthenticationTokenProvider {
    public override void Create(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context) {
        context.SetToken(context.SerializeTicket());
    }

    public override void Receive(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context) {
        context.DeserializeTicket(context.Token);

        context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary.Remove("redirect_uri"); // <-
    }
}
```

And don't forget to make the context validated in the overridden method `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.ValidateClientAuthentication`. Again, here's a simplified example which inherit from the `ApplicationOAuthProvider` class of the template project:

```
public partial class DefaultOAuthProvider:ApplicationOAuthProvider {
    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context) {
        if(null!=context.RedirectUri) {
            context.Validated(context.RedirectUri);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        return base.ValidateClientRedirectUri(context);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context) {
        if(context.TryGetFormCredentials(out String clientId, out String clientSecret)) {
            // Specify the actual expected client id and secret in your case
            if(("expected-clientId"==clientId)&&("expected-clientSecret"==clientSecret)) {

                context.Validated(); // <-

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        }

        return base.ValidateClientAuthentication(context);
    }

    public DefaultOAuthProvider(String publicClientId) : base(publicClientId) {
    }
}
```

Note that if you invoke `context.Validated` with a particular client id, then you will have to put the same client_id in the properties of the ticket, you can do that with the method `AuthenticationTokenProvider.Receive`