# How should I share authentication from a desktop application to a web application using OAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net, rest, authentication, oauth

I have a RESTful API written in ASP.Net that implements OAuth 2 for authentication, and it's currently accessed through a web application.  I've also got a legacy desktop client that accesses the same resources directly (not through the RESTful API and without OAuth, but using the same login credentials and hitting the same database).  The requirement I'm trying to meet right now is to allow a user to click a link in the desktop application in order to open the web app to a specific screen, and when they do, to have the web app authenticate automatically so that they don't have to manually log into it (since they've already logged into the desktop app).

I'm trying to work out how I can handle this within the constraints of the framework.  I'm not too familiar with OAuth 2 in general, but from what I understand I shouldn't share tokens between clients and there are no flows specifically for this kind of hand-off (unless I'm missing something).  Worst case scenario, I could generate a temporary token outside of OAuth that's used by the web client to authenticate rather than a username and password, but I'm hoping to avoid stepping outside of what's already in the framework to do what I need to do.

So the question is this: is there some decent way built into the OAuth 2.0 framework to handle this sort of "handshake" between two applications, or should I just build my own method of dealing with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using temporary one-time tokens is actually part of OAuth spec (authorization_code grant type). In this case this short-lived code can be exchanged for access_token (and refresh_token). You will have to implemenent generating and validating of this authorization_code.

If you are using OWIN OAuth middleware:

1. You can generate the code at separate API endpoint accessed by your desktop client app.
2. After receiving token, pass it to your browser and direct it to auth endpoint with `grant_type=authorization_code` over secure connection. Example: call Process.Start("https://example.com/ExternalLogin/authorization_code_goes_here"). At the webpage redirect user to your OAuth Token endpoint with `grant_type=authorization_code`.
3. AuthenticationTokenProvider.Receive will be called, in which you will validate your token. ([Example code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24698525/5056245)).
4. After successful validation OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider.GrantAuthorizationCode will be called, in which you will process the authenticated user in the same way you process it with `grant_type=password`.

Remember that your token validation logic should ensure that your tokens are short-lived, usable only once and transmitted over secure connection.

This is sometimes called "single sign-on" if you want to research this topic further.